# Not show data in razor mvc 5 ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewbag

```
var query = from c in db.TblKaryawans
                    join o in db.TblKaryawanKeluargas on c.IDKaryawan equals o.IDKaryawan
                    select new { c.Nama, o.Hubungan};

        ViewBag.karyawan = query;
        return View();
```

view

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.karyawan)
            {
                <li>@item.Hubungan</li>
            }
```

Error :

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Hubungan'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewBag` is dynamic so the view does not have any idea on the type of collection it is enumerating and thus this error. The best way is to create a ViewModel and use that instead of `anonymous types`, something like this:-

```
var query = from c in db.TblKaryawans
                    join o in db.TblKaryawanKeluargas on c.IDKaryawan equals o.IDKaryawan
                    select new MyViewModel { Nama = c.Nama, Hubungan =  o.Hubungan};
ViewBag.karyawan = query;
```

Then you can use it like this in your view:-

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<MyViewModel>)ViewBag.karyawan)
{
      <li>@item.Hubungan</li>
}
```

Where `MyViewModel` will look something like this:-

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public string Nama { get; set; }
    public string Hubungan { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ViewBag`, I would suggest using `IEnumerable<MyViewModel>` as the model to avoid run time errors when `query` is changed. The definition of `MyViewModel` class would be the same as in [@Rahul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28984396/1905949). Change your controller method as below

```
var query = from c in db.TblKaryawans
                    join o in db.TblKaryawanKeluargas on c.IDKaryawan equals o.IDKaryawan
                    select new MyViewModel { Nama = c.Nama, Hubungan =  o.Hubungan};

return View(query);
```

then make sure you have this syntax at the top of your view

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
```

and loop through the model as follows

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.Hubungan</li>
}
```